# Cómo puedo hacer ventanas emergentes personalizadas en Discord

Tags: nodejs, discord.js, bot

Llevo mucho tiempo buscando una forma de mostrar una ventana emergente para implementarla en mi bot de Discord, y me gustaría saber si es posible.

Por ejemplo, si haces clic con el botón derecho en un canal y pulsas "Eliminar canal", aparecerá una ventana emergente con un título, una descripción y botones. Esto es lo que me gustaría implementar. Es similar a los modals, pero con botones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto un paquete npm llamado discord-modals, que permitía hacer formularios con entradas de texto y menús, cuando esa función aún no estaba en discord.js, y quiero hacer algo parecido.